# If condition not working for CSS Display None

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Hi New Developer here!

I have a bunch of elements that are constantly being toggled (hiding and showing back and forth)
But I want to make it so if all the elements are hidden then display a starting/welcome message.

I started writing the if condition like this:

((the reason why I wrote if the startingContainer is NOT = to display none is because there is no way to identify for the other elements to be display block since .show() doesnt necessarily make it display block right? I could totally be wrong in saying that.))

Is it possible to write if something is not hidden then take action like the below?

```
if($('#startingContainer').css('display') != 'none'){
        //put some show functions 
         alert("completed");

}
```

Comment: Using styles as your app logic isn't a great strategy. Are you able to convert to a class-based approach or just not rely on current element state? Please show some HTML.

Comment: That will work randomly specifically with jQuery `.css` method (which detects `getComputedStyle` too). Randomly because you can hide elements using many other properties than `display` too.

Comment: Assuming simple jQuery and css is in action. Then can we conditionally add some class to the elements ( dynamically or conditionally ) so that if the class is added then the element should appear, default is none. Now instead of checking the css property of start container in the if condition, we can first find out how many elements are there in DOM with that class name. If class name elements' number is zero then we are good to show that start container. Can we try it please.

Comment: You could use the [:visible](https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) pseudo selector `if($('#startingContainer').is(':visible')) {}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this approach without using `if` block.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
#myDIV {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: lightblue;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<p>Click The Button to Toggle Displaying the Text</p>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<div id="myDIV">
  This is the Div Element with Text which will be shown or hidden when you click the Button.
</div>
```